# How to create a quantum circuit to implement the same operations but acting on different qubits?

Tags: qiskit, programming, quantum-circuit, stabilizer-code

I want the draw the quantum circuit of the following Hamiltonian:
$$H = - 4 \times X\otimes X\otimes X\otimes X - 4\times Z\otimes Z\otimes Z \otimes Z$$.
I have been able to draw the circuits of $ - X\otimes X\otimes X\otimes X$ and $- Z\otimes Z\otimes Z \otimes Z$. But adding them up using qiskit functions like compose, and combine did not give me the matrix I am looking for.

I would like to recall that when looking at $ 4 \times X\otimes X\otimes X\otimes X$ for instance, the operator $ X\otimes X\otimes X\otimes X$ will be applied $4$ times but not on the same set of qubits and the matrix should $16\times 16$.
Using compose and combine function, I still obtain the $16\times 16$ matrix by its components do not add up. Instead, the gates acted on the same set of qubits.

It will be very helpful if someone can help me. Thanks

Comment: Can I suggest you switch notation? It might help make it clearly what you're asking for. For example, let $X_2$ be $I\otimes X\otimes I\otimes I\otimes\ldots\otimes I$, so you can write things like $X_1X_2X_3X_4$ as the operator you're talking about on the first 4 qubits. Now, what do you *really* mean by $4\times X\otimes X\otimes X\otimes X$?

Comment: Yeah. But the $x_i$ are the same. There are x-Pauli matrices.
The initial form of the Hamiltonian is $H = -\sum_v As - \sum_p Bp$ where $As = X\otimes ^4$ and $Bp = Z\otimes^4$. In my case, The sum contains 4 elements for both operator.

Comment: Yes, but, as I understand it, the sets of 4 qubits are different for each term. This is the crucial thing that's missing from the question, and (I suspect) in what you're telling qiskit to do.

Comment: The sets of the 4 qubits are differents. That is true. While applying the operators As and Bp on them, the circuit of each will be the same I think. My concern is how to add up all the circuits without using combine and compose functions

Comment: Are you doing a Toric code(surface code) implementation? If so, you can check this answer:
https://entangledquery.com/t/surface-code-implementation/23/

Answer (score 0):

One can start with operator flow's tutorial of qiskit which can be found on this [website](https://qiskit.org/documentation/tutorials/operators/01_operator_flow.html). The Hamiltonian can be easily found. But since it's not a unitary matrix, the qiskit functions won't be able to build its corresponding circuit.